# An example of a non-connected space

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, connectedness

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) they say:

In complex analysis: an open subset $X\subseteq \Bbb C$ is simply connected if and only if both $X$ and its complement in the Riemann sphere are connected. The set of complex numbers with imaginary part strictly greater than zero and less than one, furnishes a nice example of an unbounded, connected, open subset of the plane whose complement is not connected.

I do not follow why $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with Re $z\leq 0$ is **not** connected.

Comment: Did you miss the "and less than one" part?

Comment: Quite.  The complement of $\{z\in\Bbb C~:~0<\text{Im}(z)<1\}$ is $\{z\in\Bbb C~:~\text{Im}(z)\leq 0~\vee \text{Im}(z)\geq 1\}$.  What path can you draw (*in the complex plane*) in this complement from the point $-i$ to the point $2i$?  (*Now ask the same question but about drawing a path on the Riemann sphere and take special note of the point at $\infty$*)

Comment: @EricWofsey I did miss it. But thank you JMoravitz too.